# How to create a listarray globally in Android Studio and show the content in a list view?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, shopping-cart

I want to create an ArrayList, add values to it from different other activities and then show it as a listview in some another activity. I know how to create a list view but I am don't know how to create an ArrayList globally and add values to it via other activities. It would be really helpful if you can provide me with a sample code for the full problem. I don't want to go for any advanced method, as it is for a beginner college project and I want to explain my implementation method properly.

Basically, it's a shopping app where I am storing the name of bought products in an ArrayList on the click of a button. And then showing the final list in listview on the cart activity.

Comment: make it static, use it where you need it

Comment: it would be great if you do some efforts and share a sample code of what you are trying to achieve so that others can understand your issue much better and help you out with that.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a class to hold the ArrayList globally:

```
public class ListHolder {
    public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Use the array list in any activity you want:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ... // Init views
        // Obtain the list
        List<String> list = ListHolder.list;
        // Maybe add something to it
        list.add("sample");
        // Set the list to your adapter to render it by your ListView
        yourAdapter.setData(list);
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked. Actually I wasn't creating the new class in the correct package before.